# XCode: Exclude abstract entities from Core Data graph

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

Is there any way to prevent abstract entities from appearing on the graph editor in XCode 7? All of my entities inherit from super abstract entities, and the graph is cluttered because the abstract entities show on the graph with arrows denoting the inheritance to their child classes. Can this be changed?

Comment: I don't think so. What are these abstract entities offering you in terms of real functionality?

Comment: Thank you. The abstract entities provide attributes which are shared by their child attributes. The NSManagedObject subclasses also have convenience methods which I added to assist with functions common to all of those types of entity.

Comment: @mashers You could continue to use class inheritance without entity inheritance.  In the model editor you include the common attributes on each entity (and don't model the abstract entity), but in the class definition you amend each subclass to inherit from the abstract entity's class.

Comment: Thank you @pbasdf - I will look into that tonight :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this cannot be changed. You can only redraw the diagram in some other program.

However, this problem points to another issue: if you have most of your entities inherit from one super parent entity, you should be aware that these will all be stored in **the same SQLite table**. This could potentially lead to performance issues and in any case could eliminate most of the efficiencies you get by having the object graph represented by a relational database in the background.

So if all your entities have, say, a `sync` field, you are better off adding this attribute to all entities or finding another scheme to keep track of syncing status.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I ended up drawing the diagram by hand by following the relationships. I had no idea that entities which inherit from an abstract entity class will be stored in the same table. I will reconsider this strategy in favour of simply copying the attributes to all of the entities and modifying my convenience methods to take the entity as a parameter (rather than being methods on the NSManagedObject sublcass and using `self` within the methods). However, performance seems perfectly adequate for now so I'll play it by ear.

Comment: Apple always use inheritance in their apps, it allows them to return multiple entities from a single fetch, e.g. in Notes they fetch accounts and folders by fetching their parent entity which is container, powerful stuff. Design your model by how it will be shown in your UI rather than thinking of it like a relational database.

Comment: @malhal Well, yes, but the Notes app is not a good example because it has very few entries and the scheme won't scale well. Nobody will have 100.000s of notes, likely no even 100s. That bein said, it is an excellent example to illustrate the tradeoffs.

Comment: I'd counter by saying no one would have 100,000 managed objects ;-) That much data would be better in a database.

Comment: @malhal You are mistaken. Core data is a wrapper around exactly that: an SQLite database. The notes app is almost certainly implementad like that. I have implemented mobile apps with 100.000s or records in Core Data. It is very performant ;-).